# Removing duplicates from the left table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I looked at some examples online, unfortunately didn't find a solution.

I have data like this.

**Table A**

```
TaskName Pattern
123      Did not find A
124      Did not find B
```

And data patterns are generated in this **Table B**

```
VariantId LocalVariantId Pattern
345       222            Did not find A
345       223            Did not find A
345       224            <Something else>
346       234            Did not find A
```

**Table C**

```
VariantId ParseRange
345       100
345       200
346       50
```

I need to combine the data from the three tables to generate data like this

```
TaskName ParseRange
123      250
```

`250` is the sum of `max(345) + max(346) = 200 + 50`

I have the query written, but the problem is duplicates in `Table B`.

From `Table C`, I do

```
select max(ParseRange) from TableC group by VariantId
```

So that gives me `200` (for `VariantId=345`)

However when I join that with `Table B`, unless I do 
    `group by TableB.VariantId`, 
I get the duplicates, so the result sum is not the same as `250`.

Here is something like the query I have

```
SELECT
    TaskName
    , SUM(TC.ParseRange)
FROM
    TableB
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            VariantId
            , MAX(ParseRange)
        FROM TableC
        GROUP BY VariantId
    ) AS TC ON TableB.VariantId = TC.VariantId
    -- also join with table A on Pattern
GROUP BY TaskName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b77bc/2/0)

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (TaskName int, Pattern varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @TableA ([TaskName], [Pattern]) VALUES
(123, 'Did not find A'),
(124, 'Did not find B');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE ([VariantId] int, [LocalVariantId] int, [Pattern] varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @TableB ([VariantId], [LocalVariantId], [Pattern]) VALUES
(345, 222, 'Did not find A'),
(345, 223, 'Did not find A'),
(345, 224, '<Something else>'),
(346, 234, 'Did not find A');

DECLARE @TableC TABLE ([VariantId] int, [ParseRange] int);
INSERT INTO @TableC ([VariantId], [ParseRange]) VALUES
(345, 100),
(345, 200),
(346, 50);
```

**Solution**

At first we make a list of all variants from `TableC` with their maximum `ParseRange` - this is `CTE_Variants`.

Then for each `VariantId` we need to find `TaskName` from `TableA`. `CROSS APPLY` does it - for each `VariantId` we are picking one related row from `TableA` with `TOP(1)`. In this example it doesn't matter which row to pick, so the query inside `CROSS APPLY` doesn't have `ORDER BY`. If your data is more complicated, you may need to add sorting to pick the correct row.

Then result is grouped by `TaskName` to calculate the final sum.

```
WITH
CTE_Variants
AS
(
    SELECT
        VariantId
        ,MAX(ParseRange) AS MaxParseRange
    FROM @TableC
    GROUP BY VariantId
)
SELECT
    CA.TaskName
    , SUM(CTE_Variants.MaxParseRange) AS SumMaxParseRange
FROM
    CTE_Variants
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) TA.TaskName
        FROM
            @TableB AS TB
            INNER JOIN @TableA AS TA ON TA.Pattern = TB.Pattern
        WHERE
            TB.VariantId = CTE_Variants.VariantId
    ) AS CA
GROUP BY
    CA.TaskName
;
```

**Result set**

```
TaskName SumMaxParseRange
123      250
```

Comment: Thanks . I used a combination of this and refactored by code a bit to get what I wanted (sorry, I forgot to update here)

Comment: @user3606175, I'm glad you found my answer useful.